# Конвертер PDU на Java

Tags: java, sms

Столкнулся с необходимостью читать входящие СМС-сообщения из 3G-модема. Путём гугления выяснил, что данные сообщения пишутся в формате PDU. Корректного конвертера на Java с поддержкой русского языка и длинных сообщений не нашёл. Подскажите, может, есть уже готовые библиотеки для работы?

Comment: Смотрел JavaME?) Вроде там есть встроенные функции для мобильных устройств

Comment: Это называется SMPP - Short Message Peer-to-Peer. Давным давно находил достаточно достоверную информацию. Даже о том, как быть с длинными и не аглицкими сообщениями.